# unable to achieve lucene solr code debugging

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm a stranger in the world of lucene-solr. I know a little about it and want to learn more of it and want to contribute in it.

Till now I've learnt to configure the solr server on any machine. But I want to learn the internal functioning of solr which I think can be done by debugging the source code of the project. I've already imported it into eclipse successfully, but is unable to debug the code.

I'm excepting a help from the community to guide me with simple steps to start with debugging of the code. I took help from internet from various blogs for this but failed to achieve the same.

I'm using solr-6.2.1.

Comment: Depending on what you want to learn and your prior knowledge, it may be better to start by either implementing the Lucene API in an application to get a feel for it and build from that, or implementing plugins for Solr. Have you seen [How to contribute](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToContribute) and looked at [How to debug Solr with Eclipse](https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/04/13/how-to-debug-solr-with-eclipse/) for setting up remote debugging in Eclipse?

Comment: .. and there is no reason to start with 6.2.1 now - go with the current git HEAD or at least the most recently released version.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh, I followed [How to debug Solr with Eclipse](https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/04/13/how-to-debug-solr-with-eclipse/) and getting a following warning.
`Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 1044`
`WARNING: Nothing to start, exiting ...`
`Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]`
`java -jar start.jar --help  for more information'

getting this when I'm starting the debugger in Eclipse.

Comment: @MatsLindh reason to choose 6.2.1 is that the place I started to work is using solr-6.2.1 and they've no such plans to move to any later version.

Comment: Have you configured the command to include all the parameters (or started it manually yourself)? `java -jar -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=1044 start.jar`?

Comment: @MatsLindh I followed every step mentioned in the link. Including the command.